# MacPorts install python25 and py25-gtk

Tags: installation, pygtk, macports, python-2.5

I am running Mac OSX 10.5.8.  I recently installed a version of macports that is compatible: MacPorts-2.0.3-10.5-Leopard.dmg.  I am trying to use this to install python25 and py25-gtk, which I have done before on other Mac systems, although they were 10.6.*.

I already have python 2.5 on this machine, but I repeated the port install just because I had done this in the past. After macports installed, I did the following commands followed by their output.

```
sudo port -v install python25
```

--->  Computing dependencies for python25

--->  Cleaning python25

--->  Removing work directory for python25

```
sudo port -v install python_select
```

--->  Cleaning python_select

--->  Removing work directory for python_select

```
sudo python_select python25
```

sudo: python_select: command not found

Needless to say python_select did not install correctly.  I also tried installing py25-gtk

```
sudo port -v install py25-gtk
```

and this takes some time to install (a few hours).  It seemed to install correctly, but still when I ran `import gtk` from my python shell i got nothing.

It seems macports is not installing the python25 and python_select, unless these are already installed and there is something wrong with the shell profile.  Basically all I need is pygtk to work with my python25 that I already have.  If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python_select has been replaced by port select

To see the possible pythons run

```
port select --list python
```

From that list choose the one you want and change to it e.g.

```
sudo port select --set python python25
```

Comment: Great thanks for that! `Selecting 'python25' for 'python' succeeded. 'python25' is now active.
`Now i did the `port install py25-gtk` again and it looks like it already installed, but I still get ImportError when trying `import gtk` in the python interpreter.

Comment: Sorry I feel like a huge nube.  How do I check the path?

Comment: I checked the .profile file that is installed with macports, and it says my path is `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`.  Then below there is a MacPorts Installer Addition: `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`  Also I check opt/local/bin, and there is a lot of gtk, and pygtk stuff in there.

Comment: so I uninstalled py25-gtk and the installed it again and it works now.  I guess you have to install this package last.